# How to make my dual threaded program work faster?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have written a program that calculates prime numbers. First I wrote "regular" code and it works great, but I wanted to make the calculation faster so i decided to split the calculations into 2 threads that calculate at the same time. Both threads are synchronized with mutexes, but it's about 4-5 times slower than my single-threaded version. Here is the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long isqrt(unsigned long x)  //function to calculate sqrt of int, not mine
{  
    register unsigned long op, res, one;  
    op = x;  
    res = 0;  
    one = 1 << 30;
    while (one > op) one >>= 2;  
    while (one != 0)
    {  
        if (op >= res + one)
        {  
            op -= res + one;  
            res += one << 1;   
        }  
        res >>= 1;  
        one >>= 2;  
    }  
    return res;  
}

static unsigned long long n; 
pthread_mutex_t lock;
pthread_mutex_t lock1;

void *threadFunc(void *arg) 
{
    unsigned long long num, x, a, b = 0, sqrtNum;   
    for(num = 3; num <= n; num += 4)
    {
        a = 0;
        sqrtNum = isqrt(num);
        for(x = 3; x <= sqrtNum; x += 2)
            if(num % x == 0)
                a++;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
        if(a == 0)
            printf("%llu\n", num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{   
    pthread_t pth;  
    unsigned long long num, x, a, b = 0, sqrtNum;
    char buff[21];
    fgets(buff, 21, stdin);
    sscanf(buff, "%llu", &n);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadFunc,"foo"); 
    for(num = 1; num <= n; num += 4)
    {       
        a = 0;
        sqrtNum = isqrt(num);
        for(x = 3; x <= sqrtNum; x += 2)
            if(num % x == 0)
                a++;    
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
        if(a == 0)
            printf("%llu\n", num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock1);
    pthread_cancel(pth);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I using mutexes improperly? As far as I get it, it should at least be as fast as one thread, but it's slower. Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: I have settled for this approach: A main thread that calculates the first half of the numbers and prints out the result and a second thread that calculates the second half paralleraly and stores the results in an array. After the main thread is done it waits for the second one to finish(the numbers the second thread calculates are larger and take a bit more time) and then prints it's array. Unfortunately this is not as fast as I'd like it to be but on very large numbers it can save many minutes of time. I might try something else later.

Comment: Why do you lock the mutex at all?

Comment: Otherwise, the results are mixed up, i.e : with mutex : 1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19... without them: 1, 3, 11, 7, 19, 13, 17.

Comment: Well yes, but that's the idea. Now you are probably sinchronizing the threads so they work like one thread but switching makes them slower. You could put them into an array and sort them at the end if you like.

Comment: Just a remark: you can change `for(x = 3; x <= sqrtNum; x += 2)` by `for(x = 3; x <= sqrtNum && a==0; x += 2)` => when you find a divider you can stop right now

Comment: Communication/synchronisation overhead. Tightly coupled threads are often slower than a single one. Either relax coupling by clearly splitting jobs between threads, use a producer/consumer pattern or stick with a single thread.

Comment: I did use an array at first, but for some reason an array larger than 1 000 000 makes a segmentation fault happen. Must be a limit of some sort. Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Comment: @МаксимАтанасов: The mutex doesn't guarantee result order though.

Comment: I have checked the order and it does match up when using  the mutex.

Comment: @МаксимАтанасов "checking the order" is not the same as a guarantee that the order will be the same in all executions of the program on all conforming implementations of the C language.

Comment: @EOF Shoudn't it be the same on every UNIX platform? Are suggesting that larger numbers may be out of order? Sorry if I don't understand you.

Comment: If you want to ensure ordering of the executions of two threads, you cannot just use `pthread_mutex_t`s. You could have a shared variable that indicates which thread's turn it is, protected by the mutex, or (more sensibly) use a `pthread_cond_t` or a `sem_t`.

Comment: I will look into some of those suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: @МаксимАтанасов  `array larger than 1 000 000 makes a segmentation fault`  Allocate the array on the heap instead of on the stack and you can have larger size arrays.

Comment: I will try that that, but I'm guessing I can't have an array with size 2^64 or anything even close.

Comment: You should put the "if (a==0)" outside of the lock - no point in locking unless you will actually print. The way it is now, it locks for each number. This will make it fast, but will more likely print results in slightly wrong order. To get ordering, create two compute threads and 1 "merge" thread. The two compute threads add items to their own array. The Merge thread watches those arrays and removes the smallest item and prints it.

Comment: Well, you can do this with two threads as well: Keep the arrays, but where you have your printfs now, it should add to its array, then check the other threads' array for a lower number. Only when both arrays are non-empty can you remove the lowest result and print.

Comment: I have made the threads save to arrays,The calculations themselves are very fast(twice as fast), but printing out the array takes quite a while and the single-threaded version is still faster and uses a whole lot less memory  as there are no gigantic arrays. I will try something else later. Thanks